# What springboard type UI components is this app using?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, ios4, uikit

What sort of springboard like UI component is this application using?

http://quickbinsapp.com/

It is very similar to the generic iphone springboard / home screen app launcher except this is an application that uses draggable contacts. I'd like to build something similar except instead of contacts have my own custom objects that are draggable around the screen but managed on a grid similar to the springboard / home screen and like in this app?

What should I be reading up on or looking at? I haven't found anything in the SDK yet. Does it have be custom built?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you want is springboard-like functionality, the AQGridView code includes an example that's halfway there to what you'd need, and you don't have to pull in all of Three20 to use it. (Three20 projects and UIKit projects don't like to coexist typically.)

Comment: You can download the AQGridView here https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what they're using, but the Three20 project has a springboard-like component